# Print DVD Table of content

Tags: dvd, printing, table-of-contents

is there a tool or something that I can use to print my DVD table of content? I have a lot of folders and subfolders and I need to have them printed on paper.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tree` command or `dir` command to produce a file listing, and then save it to a file and print that. for example, open a command prompt by pressing `win+r` and then typing `cmd` and pressing enter. Type `cd` and then the path to the folder, using quotes if there are spaces. for example,

```
cd "C:\Users\Your Name\Documents"
```

Alternatively, if you're using Windows 7 or Windows Vista, open the folder and hold shift while right clicking. There should be an "Open command prompt here" option.

Then, run the command

```
tree > tree.txt
```

This will create a file called tree.txt with a heirarchical listing of folders and files. You can just use notepad or another text editor to print this.

Comment: Even if this doesn't give me the entire directory listing, it's kinda good!

Comment: `tree` just displays the folder tree, not any files. `tree /f` will display the files in each folder, but will skip any hidden files. If you have problems printing the line graphic characters, `tree /a /f` will use simpler text characters for the lines.

Comment: As an alternative, `dir /a /b /s > file.txt` will get a complete text listing of files and folders. (If you don't need hidden files, leave out the `/a`.) Each line will have the entire folder path name, so if you have deeply nested folders the list can get rather wide. If you started from a sub-directory instead of the root of a drive, you can use Find and Replace in a text editor to remove the common beginning part of the path.